# rpmbuild unable to find files

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am having issues with a specfile that I created not being able to find the files in the tar.gz file. I have dumped the contents of the spec file here. The tar.gz file is in ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES. I will put the tar listing below as well.

```
Name:           pyvaders
Version:        1
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        Space Invaders is a classic arcade game from the 1980s. PyInvaders is an implementation of this in python.
License:        MIT
URL:            https://github.com/nixbytes/pyvaders
Source0:        pyvaders-1.1.tar.gz
BuildArch:      noarch
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{release}-buildroot

BuildRequires:  python%{python3_pkgversion}-devel
BuildRequires:  python%{python3_pkgversion}-setuptools

%description
Space Invaders is a classic arcade game from the 1980s. PyInvaders is an implementation of this in python

Requires:       python3-pygame
%prep
#mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/bin/pyvaders

%build
%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
cp -aR pyvaders-1/ $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
#mv pyvaders-1.1/* $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
%check

%files
%attr(0744, root, root)
/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/alien_enemy.png
/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/alien.png
/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/darkgrey_02.png
/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/explosion.wav
/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/laser.png
/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/laser.wav
/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/Monoton-Regular.ttf
/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/Monotro-License
/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/mountains03-1920-x-1080_full.png
/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/mountains03-512-x-256_full.png
/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/space-bg.jpg
/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/__init__.py
/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/main.py
```

Here's the output of the tar file

```
tar -tvf pyvaders-1.1.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x z/z               0 2020-12-03 20:43 usr/
drwxr-xr-x z/z               0 2020-12-03 20:43 usr/local/
drwxr-xr-x z/z               0 2020-12-03 20:43 usr/local/bin/
drwxr-xr-x z/z               0 2020-12-03 20:43 usr/local/bin/pyvaders/
-rw-r--r-- z/z               0 2020-12-03 20:43 usr/local/bin/pyvaders/__init__.py
-rwxr-xr-x z/z            4881 2020-12-03 20:43 usr/local/bin/pyvaders/main.py
drwxr-xr-x z/z               0 2020-12-03 20:43 usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assests/
-rwxr-xr-x z/z           51604 2020-12-03 20:43 usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assests/Monoton-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r-- z/z            4527 2020-12-03 20:43 usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assests/Monotro-License
-rw-r--r-- z/z            1847 2020-12-03 20:43 usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assests/alien.png
-rw-r--r-- z/z           10015 2020-12-03 20:43 usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assests/alien_enemy.png
-rw-r--r-- z/z            7587 2020-12-03 20:43 usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assests/darkgrey_02.png
-rw-r--r-- z/z          336406 2020-12-03 20:43 usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assests/explosion.wav
-rw-r--r-- z/z            3086 2020-12-03 20:43 usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assests/laser.png
-rw-r--r-- z/z           34252 2020-12-03 20:43 usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assests/laser.wav
-rw-r--r-- z/z          142152 2020-12-03 20:43 usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assests/mountains03-1920-x-1080_full.png
-rw-r--r-- z/z           41767 2020-12-03 20:43 usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assests/mountains03-512-x-256_full.png
-rw-r--r-- z/z          373464 2020-12-03 20:43 usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assests/space-bg.jpg
```

Here's the error message

```
 File not found: /home/z/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/pyvaders-1-1.fc33.x86_64/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/alien_enemy.png
    File not found: /home/z/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/pyvaders-1-1.fc33.x86_64/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/alien.png
    File not found: /home/z/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/pyvaders-1-1.fc33.x86_64/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/darkgrey_02.png
    File not found: /home/z/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/pyvaders-1-1.fc33.x86_64/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/explosion.wav
    File not found: /home/z/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/pyvaders-1-1.fc33.x86_64/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/laser.png
    File not found: /home/z/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/pyvaders-1-1.fc33.x86_64/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/laser.wav
    File not found: /home/z/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/pyvaders-1-1.fc33.x86_64/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/Monoton-Regular.ttf
    File not found: /home/z/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/pyvaders-1-1.fc33.x86_64/usr/local/bin/pyvaders/assets/Monotro-Licens
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the tar extraction inside the `%prep` section like so:

```
%prep
%autosetup
```

The [`%autosetup`](https://rpm.org/user_doc/autosetup.html) macro will extract archives and apply `Patch`es (if any) to the extracted source tree. It can be used instead of older `%setup -q`.

Comment: Still unable to locate the files.

I changed the structure of the tar file as well.

Comment: The tar file should extract with its top level dir to `%{name}-%{version}`, e.g. `pyvaders-1`. If this is not how you structured your archive, things will fail. You can either recompress in a way as it expects or specify that as `-n` parameter to `%autosetup`, e.g. `%autosetup -n dirname-once-extracted`

Comment: @ Danila Vershinin I was able to figure it out, thanks for pointing it out to others!